# Reading Multiple JSON Files in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make my program read data from three similar JSON files. However, when I try to print them in the public static main class, I keep on getting errors. Kindly, can someone tell me where is my problem? Thank you! I am preparing them for my Java GUI and hopefully going to be linking the three files into a button that will invoke them all.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class JSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        new JSON();
    }


    public JSON() throws IOException, ParseException {
        lfcJSON();
        ifcJSON();
        afcJSON();

    }

    private void lfcJSON() throws IOException, ParseException {

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/LFCSquad.json");
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONObject lfcJsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        String tName = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("teamName");
        String hTown = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("homeTown");
        BigDecimal fYear = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("founded");

        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) lfcJsonObj.get("players");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject players = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
            String name = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("name");
            BigDecimal age = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("age");
            BigDecimal goals = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("goals");
            BigDecimal assists = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("assists");
            BigDecimal kitNum = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("kitNumber");
            String pos = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("posisiton");
            String country = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("nationality");


        }
    }
        private void ifcJSON() throws IOException, ParseException {

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/IFCSquad.json");
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JSONObject ifcJsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

            String tName = (String) ifcJsonObj.get("teamName");
            String hTown = (String) ifcJsonObj.get("homeTown");
            BigDecimal fYear = (BigDecimal) ifcJsonObj.get("founded");

            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) ifcJsonObj.get("players");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject players = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                String name = (String) ifcJsonObj.get("name");
                BigDecimal age = (BigDecimal) ifcJsonObj.get("age");
                BigDecimal goals = (BigDecimal) ifcJsonObj.get("goals");
                BigDecimal assists = (BigDecimal) ifcJsonObj.get("assists");
                BigDecimal kitNum = (BigDecimal) ifcJsonObj.get("kitNumber");
                String pos = (String) ifcJsonObj.get("posisiton");
                String country = (String) ifcJsonObj.get("nationality");

            }
        }
        private void afcJSON () throws IOException, ParseException {

           JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
           FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/AFCSquad.json");
           Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
           JSONObject lfcJsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
           String tName = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("teamName");
           String hTown = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("homeTown");
           BigDecimal fYear = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("founded");
           JSONArray array = (JSONArray) lfcJsonObj.get("players");

           for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

              JSONObject players = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
              String name = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("name");
              BigDecimal age = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("age");
              BigDecimal goals = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("goals");
              BigDecimal assists = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("assists");
              BigDecimal kitNum = (BigDecimal) lfcJsonObj.get("kitNumber");
              String pos = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("posisiton");
              String country = (String) lfcJsonObj.get("nationality");

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: show me your logcat?

Comment: [Edit] your question and post details of the errors you are getting. In other words, post the error message you are getting and also the stack trace.